# List of mac operation names

Tags: macos

I was wondering is there some specific place where I can lookup for the `names` of mac commands so I can rebind them in System Preferences, because I'm coming from a Win background and currently I'm forced to work with a mac because of a project and its quite frustrating. For example at least the following commands:

1. find/search (is vital),
2. name of ctrl+b? (so I can replace it)
3. name of ctrl+a? (so I can replace it)
4. name of ctrl+v? (so I can replace it)
5. if I think of any additional I'll add them to the list... (Most of them are obvious(Cut/Paste/Copy) but not all.)

Answer (score 0):

First… don't replace them, learn them.
Some simply cannot be replaced unless you start hacking around in [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) & will just make your life harder, long-term.

Most of the common ones are the same as Windows, just using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  instead of  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  - cut/copy/paste etc. Some are app-specific - Undo/redo is sometimes  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>Z</kbd>  /  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>    <kbd>Z</kbd>  & sometimes the legacy version  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>Z</kbd>  /  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>Y</kbd>  - so you can't map that one out.

The find command is different depending on whether you are searching in-app [simply  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd>  ] or whether you want to invoke Spotlight -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Space</kbd>

The Mac is massively key-commandable right out of the box. There are so many that most people never learn them all, though it's well worth having a go at learning them.

There's a switcher's guide at [Apple KB - Mac tips for Windows switchers](https://support.apple.com/HT204216) which then links through to the full set of default global key commands for the more adventurous.

Comment: Appreciate the comment, but the point is that I'm using these keys for something far better (for example ctrl+b is  1 symbol backwards and ctrl+f is 1 symbol forward), which in my opinion is completely irrelevant when you have arrow keys? It's not about learning them, that I can do but the point is that I already have other mappings in their places which are far better (given the above as example).  Also I've already managed to replace some of the "unwanted" shortcuts in such way, I just need their names and everything will be perfectly customisable.

Comment: "ctrl+b is 1 symbol backwards" … that's a global. It's also only there for unix legacy compatibility. Most Mac users won't even know it exists. You're going to need Karabiner for that [or for any global]. Some of these are also contextual. I will maintain you're fighting a losing battle. This question gets asked so many times & there is no simple 'make it like Windows' fix.

Comment: Also "something far better"… don't be mysterious, tell us what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than how you think you need to achieve it.

Comment: Goal is to make the transition to mac with little effort as possible. In vs-code: Ctrl+b was used for go to definition, instead i have to change muscle memory to alt+b (which is cmd+b in mac). Ctrl+f for find (instead of alt+f) ctrl+a (instead of alt+a) and so on...

Comment: …well, that added rather than removed confusion. Anyway - Karabiner is about the only thing that can do what you want. You will struggle with anything contextual - plus e.g VS Code is nothing like most other apps. It's neither fish nor fowl, so keys you remap in there will break things elsewhere.

Comment: I will look into it when I have free time and try to solve things that way. The reason why I want to override them from outside of vs code is that even though I put keymaps within vs code it still uses the main maps from mac.

Comment: Actually... nevermind, my bad I just needed to pin them within vs code, that was my bad. I thought that they were not  overriddable , but it was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to learn keybinds on a Mac:
[Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

this is apple's intro to changing keybinds:
[Use macOS keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/keyboard-shortcuts-mchlp2262/mac)

as an addendum - you can kind of see that apple has a lot of the relevant docs in their support, perhaps check it out

Comment: I have checked the second link and here is the thing: in the links they tell you `what` the cmd shortcut key does but not what its `key/name` is . Example given: "Command-t:  Open a new tab" if you add "Open new tab" in system preferences> shortcuts>app shorcuts as a key,it will not work, but if you add "New Tab" (case_sensitive) it will work, which is the subtle difference and I was hoping to find some resources with the `key names`. So far I`ve just guessed their names judging from the jobs they do and have succeeded for most of them but I still have some missing.

Comment: ahh, i see I misunderstood what you wanted. unfortunately I do not know the proper what the key names are, or where to find them. sorry :(